# Should I use != or == first when implementing an if else for comparison

Tags: java, android, if-statement, operators

This has been bugging me for a while and I'm not sure if there is a correct answer:

Take these two statements

```
if(foo == bar)
    do this;
else if(foo != bar)
    do that;
```

or

```
if(foo != bar)
    do that;
else if(foo == bar)
    do this;
```

which one of these is correct (forgetting optimization for now)
My mind tells me that the answer depends on what result is expected for example if this was running in a loop and I predicted that foo will be equal to bar more times than it is not then the first one would be correct.

Is there any efficiency implications between the notations?

Comment: Let the JITC worry about that level of optimization.  Worry about what makes your code the most readable.

Comment: Agreed. More readable code. This basically then equals to specific data used to compare. If you are mainly having database of names and most are John's.. and you're more curious about non-Johns, you'd use != "John" .. and vice versa.

Comment: And that's a general rule, not just at this level of granularity. Code for human comprehensibility first; the computer is faster than you think.

Comment: Why not use `else` instead of `else if`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman because there maybe more variables involved, think you miss the point of the question

Comment: As has been said, it’s a matter of readability. Personally I generally find the `==` variant most readable. After having spelled my way through code like `notFound != false` I have acquired an aversion against unnecessary negations.

Comment: I didn’t get the part about more variables being involved either. Please explain, @Rob85.

Comment: my point to not writing an else was to see if there would be any reason to do it one way or the other

Comment: You mean, you didn’t want any readability difference between `==` and `!=` to play a role, therefore you made an example where we need to use both? Is that it?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes exactly :-) i think it boils down to - is there any difference in performance between the two operators, most people here say no, Rotwang states otherwise below. i was curious that if this type of statement written either way was in a large loop would one potentially be quicker, and the fact that when coding sometimes i sometime switch between the two and wanted to find out if there was a correct way.

Comment: Keep your code positive whenever possible.

Answer (score 5):

*But is there any efficiency implications between the notations?* No. None at all. Prefer the one that is most readable. If it reads better saying "if not `a`" in a sentence, use `!`. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: It is possible that conditions have side effects. In that case it might matter not from an efficiency standpoint but to prevent wrong outcomes. So `if ((nr = in.read(...)) < 0) { ignore(); } else if (nr == 0) { ... } else { ... }` won't work if you alter the order of the conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to go for If...else condition , you can use ternary operator .

like 
result = testStatement ? value1 : value2;

But for nested conditions , ternary operator looks very complex.

Answer (score 1):

It really does make much of a difference, optimisation wise. It comes down to your style and preferences. Both of your examples have the same impact.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this

```
if(foo == bar)
do this;
else 
do that;
```

Seems clearer that way, and if you are returning any statements inside the conditional blocks, it makes the program more readable

Comment: And it also uses less operations. And the faster one: `==` is faster than `!=` in that it is just a single comparison and not a comparison + a negation.

Comment: @Rotwang can you write an answer as that is fairly intresting

Comment: @Rob85 Well, it might or not be an issue, since ProGuard can optimize your code, but I always prefer to write an already optimized code, as if the compiler was stupid. I do so since my VB and VB.NET times. And on limited machines like mobile devices I still have the feeling I must squeeze the byte.

Comment: @LewBloch I don't need curly braces

Comment: I'm afraid you do need curly braces around your conditional and loop statements, @Kenny Togunloju. Code that lives gets modified, often. Lack of curly braces can lead and has led to error when code is modified. All Java coding standards call for curly braces, including Oracle's own http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449 and Google's https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are asking about the difference between the following two snippets.

```
if (predicate1()) {
    doThis();
} else if (predicate2()) {
    doThat();
}

if (predicate2()) {
    doThat();
} else if (predicate1()) {
    doThis();
}
```

If predicate1 and predicate2 may both be true at the same time, there is a difference in the outcome, I am sure you are aware of that. So I will assume that at most one of them can be true. I am also assuming that we can safely ignore any side effects from evaluating the conditions.

Is there a readability difference? Not as the code stands. However, in a concrete situation it could well be that the average reader will find it more natural to evaluate one predicate first. If so, go by that.

You ask about efficiency. First answer is, you shouldn’t. But anyway, there are two guidelines, and I think you have touched on both already:

- Evaluate the condition that is true most often first
- Evaluate the condition that is cheapest to evaluate first

If we had numbers, we could make a fine piece of math calculating the average cost of each snippet and choose the best.

As to whether `==` or `!=` is cheaper, with my attitude I obviously don’t know the answer. I would expect it to vary with the types you compare, with whether you are running byte code or native code, with your type of CPU and other factors. You may go measure, and there may be folks around that know a rule thumb or two. In any case, the difference has to be very minute.